# Run function foreach item when button isClicked in React Typescript

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, arraylist, foreach

I have to create buttons no. of times depends on my array so I did the following

```
    const Sandbox = () => {
  const [isClicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  const clickMe = (): void => {
    
    console.log("say hello new");
    setClicked(!isClicked);

    
  };

  let buttonContents = [
    { id: 1, Title: "One", Description: "First" }, //isClicked
    { id: 2, Title: "Two", Description: "Second" },
    { id: 3, Title: "Three", Description: "Third" },
    { id: 4, Title: "Four", Description: "Fourth" },
  ];
  let buttonContentsList: any[] = [];

 
  buttonContents.forEach((item) => {
    buttonContentsList.push(
      <BigButton
        onClick={() => {
          clickMe(); 
        }}
        Title={item.Title}
        Description={item.Description}
        clicked={isClicked}
      ></BigButton>
    );
  });

  return <>{buttonContentsList}</>;
};

export default Sandbox;
```

When I do this and click on a button all my buttons get selected. But I wanted only one button to be selected and when the other button is clicked state should change of the current button which is clicked to be unselected and the other to click to be selected, so then only one button is clicked in the group of buttons. The code given here is from the parent component and I do pass the props and state to the child which has no issue. What change should I make here to achieve what I needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want. But closest to your solution is:

```js
import {useState} from 'react'

const Sandbox = () => {
  const [clickedId, setClickedId] = useState(null);

  const clickMe = (id) => setClickedId(id);

  let buttonContents = [
    { id: 1, Title: "One", Description: "First" },
    { id: 2, Title: "Two", Description: "Second" },
    { id: 3, Title: "Three", Description: "Third" },
    { id: 4, Title: "Four", Description: "Fourth" },
  ];
  let buttonContentsList = [];
 
  buttonContents.forEach((item) => {
    buttonContentsList.push(
     <BigButton
       onClick={() => {
          clickMe(item.id); 
       }}
       Title={item.Title}
       Description={item.Description}
       clicked={clickedId === item.id}
     ></BigButton>
    );
  });

  return <>{buttonContentsList}</>;
};

export default Sandbox;
```

Sorry I made some modifications to the button component. But I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Hi, @Dmitrii Zolotuhin thanks for your answer. With my requirement clicked is a boolean variable which I need to update my state to pass it to my child component. Therefore I should be able to do setClicked only for an item. So do you know how can I do it.

Comment: @JoeKevinRayan, in your case it will be just `clicked={clickedId === item.id}`

Comment: @JoeKevinRayan, I've modified the answer and user your button component.

Comment: I did understand you've changed my component there but didn't get the logic coz I'm passing isClicked boolean value to my child component. Tried this its working now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JoeKevinRayan, so basically it works because you "memorizing" ID of clicked element and then on  `buttonList`  rerender we do something like "if current memorized ID equals item ID return true to  `clicked` button prop"

Comment: yup i got that one thanks again.